# Why is React.useId() returning invalid ids?

Tags: typescript, react-18

A functional component is implemented like this :

```
const TestComponent = () => {
   const id1 = React.useId();
   const id2 = React.useId();
   const id3 = React.useId();

   return (
     <div>{ JSON.stringify([ id1, id2, id2 ]) }</div>
   );
}
```

display this

```
[ ":Rkm:", ":RkmH1:", ":RkmH2:" ]
```

These ids seems not valid, why does React return these values?

#### ** EDIT **

According to [the official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useid), `React.useId()` is used to assign `id` HTML attributes :

```
function Checkbox() {
  const id = useId();
  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor={id}>Do you like React?</label>
      <input id={id} type="checkbox" name="react"/>
    </>
  );
};
```

And, according to the [HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) [specifications](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute), `id` attributes simply "must contain at least one character" and "must not contain any ASCII whitespace." However, React's documentation also states :

> **Note**
>
> `useId` generates a string that includes the `:` token. This helps ensure that the token is unique, but is not supported in CSS selectors or APIs like `querySelectorAll`.

So, why returning values that aren't compatible with `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: Why are these ids not valid to you? These values are all unique - seems good enough to me.

Comment: @Evert what is the purpose, then? Because **both** examples on [the official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useid) use it this way!!

Comment: @YanickRochon ah I was wrong. Deleted my comment. Why do you need to use it with QuerySelectAll ?

Comment: @Evert I simply want to understand why this is so; what good is there that these IDs are simply not unique within their own context, and let users handle the rest? Why making it incompatible with query selectors? As far as my usage is concerned, I typically use these ids are suffixes, like `const id = "form-element-" + React.useId();`, for example.